# A subset of a vector bundle

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth $m$-manifold, $p\in M$, $l\in\mathbb{N}$, $\pi:E\to M$ be a smooth vector bundle, $\nabla, \nabla'$ be connections of $E$ and $TM$, respectively. $\Gamma(E)$ denotes the space of smooth sections of $E$. $E_p:=\pi^{-1}(\{p\})\subset E$.

Then we can consider the Whitney sum
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{E}:=E\oplus(E\otimes T^\ast M)\oplus\cdots\oplus(E\otimes (T^\ast M^{\otimes l}))
\end{eqnarray}
and the subset
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{V}_p :=&\{u(p)\oplus\nabla u(p)\oplus \cdots\oplus\nabla^l u(p)\vert u\in\Gamma(E)\}&\subset\mathbb{E}_p, \\
\mathbb{V} :=&\sqcup_{p\in M}\mathbb{V}_p&\subset\mathbb{E}.
\end{eqnarray}

Question:

(i) Does $\mathbb{V}$ foam a smooth subbundle of $\mathbb{E}$?

(ii) Suppose $g$ be a smooth Riemannian metric of $M$ and $\nabla'$ be the LeviCivita connection. Does $\mathbb{V}$ depend on $g$ ?

(iii) Are there any simple description of $\mathbb{V}$ in which the arbitrary smooth section $u\in\Gamma(E)$ doesn't appear ?

Comment: When $\nabla'$ is torsion-free (so that $\nabla^k u$ is symmetric) you should be able to show $\mathbb V = E \oplus (E \otimes T^*M) \oplus \cdots \oplus (E \otimes \text{Sym}^l T^* M)$ by constructing a section $u$ with arbitrary first $l$ derivatives at a point in local coordinates. Try to see what happens when you try this with torsion.

Comment: In tortion-free case, $(\nabla\nabla u)(X,Y)-(\nabla\nabla u)(Y,X)=R^\nabla(X,Y)u$ ($X,Y\in\Gamma(TM)$). Therefore $\nabla\nabla u\in\Gamma(E\otimes T^\ast M\otimes T^\ast M)$ is not symmetric in general.

Comment: Right, my mistake, this is tougher than I thought. Still, at second order I think this reduces the dependence on $u$ to studying the (linear!) curvature endomorphism, so it's probably worth pursuing. (Perhaps you can get something like $\mathbb V \cap T^* M^{\otimes 2} = \text{Sym}^2 (T^*M) \oplus \text{im}R^\nabla$? It's not clear to me offhand.) I don't know enough about jet bundles to answer this question well.

Comment: Actually I think (up to second order) it's like a graph of $R^\nabla$ - we get something like $\mathbb V_p = \{ (\xi, T^* M \otimes E, R^\nabla(\xi) + \text{Sym}^2 T^*M \otimes E, \ldots) \colon \xi \in E\}$.

Comment: A nicer way of phrasing your question is that you're looking for the image of the jet bundle $J^l E$ under the natural map $J^l E \to \mathbb E$ induced by the connections, perhaps you can google your way to some progress.

Comment: Thank you for a good keyword.